# JS and HTML-form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to be able to insert text from a form after clicking a submit button. The text should then be hashed by my custom javascript function as specified below.

This is my code:

```
var translate = function (text) {
  var hash = {
       "A": "B",
       "C": "D",
       "E": "F",
       "a": "b",
       "c": "d",
       "e": "f"
  } ;

  return text.replace (/. / g, function (char) {
     return hash [char] || char;
  });
} ;

translate ('ABE')// BCF
```

The problem is I don't know how to connect this code to my HTML form.

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="textform" id="textform">
<p><textarea name=""text" id=""text" cols="48" rows="8"></textarea>
</p>
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Go" />
</p>
</form>
```

It is desirable to give an example of how to embed these pieces of code to the page to make it work. Thank you.

**P.S.** I am an absolute beginner, so do not be surprised by my questions.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that function? Display it in an element for the user to see, submit it to the server, both?

Comment: I would like to see this code is executed on the page. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the extra quotation marks before "name" and "id" attributes of your `<textarea>`

1. Create an event handler for the form's submit event.
2. Within that handler, replace the textarea's value with the translated value.
3. Optionally do not allow the form to submit (not sure if you need this).

put this code on your page anywhere after the `</form>` tag:

```
<script>
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  // if you DO want the form to submit then get rid of the next 2 lines
  e = e ? e : window.event;
  e.preventDefault();

  var t = document.getElementById('text');
  t.value = translate(t.value);
});
</script>
```